# Error connecting to docker container

Tags: linux, docker, containers

I installed a service on a remote Linux computer using docker. I used the following commands

- git clone https://github.com/OpenVidu/openvidu-tutorials.git
- npm install -g http-server
- http-server openvidu-tutorials/openvidu-getaroom/web
- docker run -p 4443:4443 --rm -e openvidu.secret=MY_SECRET -e openvidu.publicurl=https://187.84.228.66:4443 openvidu/openvidu-server-kms

But when I try do connect at the first time, I received the follow error menssage:

> "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE", and sometime "ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED"

I used the following diagnostic command in Linux computer “docker ps” and received the following response:

> CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES
>   21b0620266cd openvidu/openvidu-server-kms:latest "/usr/bin/supervisor 5 days ago >Up 5 days 8443/tcp, 8888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4443->4443/tcp, 9091/tcp sick_ritchie

What is wrong? How can I solve this?

Comment: I have no clue wrt the answe to ur problem, but it might be easier if you named the container.  Name the container.  Then edit the question to show revised run command and paste in ur exec command.

Comment: I'll guess that it's related to the `https` protocol. how did you access this container? can you try to do it via `http` instead (and change the `publicurl` as well)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure sure what causes this, but when I had the same problem (with different http server) I changed listening on particular ip address (which was *127.0.0.1* in my case) to listening on all interfaces - *0.0.0.0*.

I mean http server configuration, not *Docker* configuration.